# How to use node.js as a production web server?

Tags: node.js

I'm currently developing a project using node, and as I'm approaching the launch, I'm struggling to find resources on how to setup node for use on a commercial, production server. Most resources I have seen have consisted of contrived, simple examples without taking into account scalability and fault tolerance. So, my question is, can anybody offer advice or point me to resources for setting up a node installation that:

- Is fault tolerant. If an instance crashes, it needs to be logged and restarted
- Creating a pool of node instances that can be load balanced
- Provide useful insights into resource usage
- Production node security practices
- Anything else that would be helpful in a production web environment that I am surely missing

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Check out this link: http://cuppster.com/2011/05/12/diy-node-js-server-on-amazon-ec2

For load balancing and static content delivering i would use nginx.

Comment: +1 For the useful link - also check the follow up to that blogpost: http://cuppster.com/2011/05/18/using-supervisor-with-upstart

Comment: Great. Thanks for the resources. I'll check them out.

Answer (score -2):

Amazon EC2 was mentioned by @zaub3r3r so I think it's only fair to mention Joyent. No commercial relation, I'm just a huge fanboy of their team:

- The gurus of node.js best practice are [Ryan Dahl](https://github.com/ry) and [Isaac Schlueter](http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm).
- The gurus of insight into resource usage are [Bryan](http://dtrace.org/blogs/bmc/) [Cantrill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) and [Brendan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132091518) [Gregg](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1809426).
- The gurus of server and cloud ops are [Ben Rockwood](http://cuddletech.com/blog/) and [Mark Mayo](http://joyeur.com/2011/04/24/magical-block-store-when-abstractions-fail-us/).

I guess my point is: even if you don't go for cloud hosting, pay attention to what these guys say.

Comment: DO you have specific articles they might've written on the subject?

Comment: @Paul Which subject in particular?

Comment: . . . The original poster's subject?  How to best setup a node.js production server?